# Filter By Category using Dropdown in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to filter some products by categories using the `Dropdown`. The filter worked very well, but the category in the `Dropdown` only showed the categories result, e.g there's a Coffee, and Tea category, if I select Tea, the dropdown only showed the Tea category, unlike before, showing every category available.

Controller :

```
    if(request()->category_filter){
        $resultCategory = request()->category_filter;
        $products = Product::where('category_id', $resultCategory)->with(['category', 'image'])->get();
    }else{
        $products = Product::with(['category', 'image'])->get();
    }

    return view('home.products', compact('products'));
```

View :

```
@extends('home.layouts.app')

@section('page-content')
    <section class="section-padding" id="products">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <h2 class="mb-5 text-center">Products</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2 filter mb-3 text-center">
                    <div class="row">
                        <p>Category</p>
                        <div class="col">
                            <form action="{{ route('homepage.products') }}" method="get">
                                <select name="category_filter" id="category_filter" class="form-select mb-2">
                                    @foreach ($products as $p)
                                        <option value="{{ $p->category->id }}">{{ $p->category->name }}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-search"></i> Search</button>
                                <a href="{{ route('homepage.products') }}" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-arrow-rotate-left"></i> Reset</a>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    @foreach ($products as $p)
                        <div class="col-3">
                            <div class="portfolio-thumb mb-5">
                                @foreach ($p->image as $image)
                                    <a href="{{ asset('storage/'.$image->path) }}" class="image-popup">
                                        <img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$image->path) }}" class="img-fluid portfolio-image" alt="">
                                    </a>
                                    @break
                                @endforeach
                                <div class="portfolio-info">
                                    <h5 class="text-black">{{ $p->name }}</h5>
                                    <h6 style="color:{{ $p->category->indicator }};">{{ $p->category->name }}</h6>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should query the categories separately from the products, so when you filter the products, the category list will not be affected.

```
if (request()->category_filter) {
    $resultCategory = request()->category_filter;
    $products = Product::where('category_id', $resultCategory)->with(['image'])->get();
} else {
    $products = Product::with(['image'])->get();
}
$categories = Category::whereHas('products')->get();

return view('home.products', compact('products', 'categories'));
```

Then in your blade, just loop the `$categories` variable

```
<select name="category_filter" id="category_filter" class="form-select mb-2">
    @foreach ($categories as $category)
        <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: This code worked well. But i had to revised the Controller code you gave because it returned `Undefined Method App\Models\ProductCategory::product()` ( i had to change the Category model because my product category is using ProductCategory model) and change the `$categories` variables into `$categories = ProductCategory::all();` to avoid the error. Other than that, it's fine. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You dont have a relation `products` in the ProductCategory model ?

Comment: i indeed have, i forgot to show the Models code.